Whatsapp Business API: Product sets not appearing on whatsapp catalog
I am using whatsapp business platform. I created a catalog using commerce manager and have connected it to my Whatsapp Business Account. Now, I want to create sets/collection in my catalog.
When I try to create it using this documentation The set was created but I cannot see any 'publish' option to make the changes appear on the Whatsapp as well.
When I followed this documentation I get an error saying
{
"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '<Product_Catalog_id>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": ""
}

}
I have been sending msgs using this same catalog id. Then what could be the problem here? How can we make and publish sets for Whatsapp? Also, for publish_to_shops, shop ids are needed. Where can I find one for my whatsapp? As the WABA id is not considered a shop id.
UPDATE: Solved the issue of 'Unsupported post request. Object with ID '<Product_Catalog_id>' does not exist'. It was missing a permission called catalog_management.
But still cannot find anything to publish the sets on whatsapp catalog.
How can we make categories on whatsapp catalog using whatsapp API?
